# Getting SQL Procedure ResultSet Information

Tags: sql-server-2012

For SQL Server 2012, any idea how to get the results from a SQL stored procedure without running it?

Closest I found find is from sp_depends which has a selected but it gives me results even when its in the where statement.

Hoping to find a way to find what columns are selected, but not in where statement.

Let me rephrase a little bit: I don't need the data, just what columns it returns, so I can create my result classes via a T4.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're trying to do in a SP might be doable in a function instead. You can do many of the same things in a custom function that you can in simple stored procedures, but functions aren't "run" like a stored procedure (i.e. exec sp_blah)

I can create a function like this:

```
 create function CustomAdd @i int, @ii int
 returns int
 as 
 return (@i + @ii)
```

Then any time I want to use it I would write something like:

```
select CustomAdd(343,4343)
```